# Accessing volley response with callback interfaces

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley

I m trying to extract android volley response to a member variable of the same class. I used callback interfaces to perform this task :

```
public void getData(MyCustomListener customListener) {

JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
      response -> {
              Log.i("response",response.toString());
              customListener.onResponse(completeCart);

              },
      error -> Log.i("Volley_error", error.getMessage())) {
      ...
```

CustomerListener interface:

```
public interface MyCustomListener {

    public void onResponse(Object response);

    public void onError(String error_response);
}
```

And inside `onCreateView` method of the fragment :

```
getData(new MyCustomListener() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Object response) {
        completeCartProItems.addAll((List<CompleteCartProItem>) response);
                }

     @Override
       public void onError(String error_response) {}
            });
```

When I put a debug pointer at `completeCartProItems.addAll((List<CompleteCartProItem>) response);` **response** is not empty but **completeCartProItems** arraylist is shown as empty.

[image]

Variables :

[image]

I need to pass this `completeCartProItems` to a Adapter named `CartItem_ScrollerAdapter` which has implemented to a `RecycleView`.

This implementation also inside the `onCreateView` of the fragment. right after calling `getData()` method :

```
cart_item_scrollerAdapter = new CartItem_ScrollerAdapter(getActivity(), completeCartProItems);
```

I put debug pointer inside the constructor of the `CartItem_ScrollerAdapter` as well.

[image]

But it also shows that the List parameter of the constructor is empty.
[image]

How to pass not empty `ArrayList` to the adapter given below ?? Any suggestions will be appreciable. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

> Adapter class :

```
public class CartItem_ScrollerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItem_ScrollerAdapter.CartItemViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<CompleteCartProItem> completeCartProItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;


    public CartItem_ScrollerAdapter(Context context,  List<CompleteCartProItem> completeCartProItems) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.completeCartProItems = completeCartProItems;
    }

    @Override
    public CartItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);
        CartItemViewHolder cartItemViewHolder = new CartItemViewHolder(view);
        return cartItemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CompleteCartProItem proItem = completeCartProItems.get(position);
        CartDetails details = (CartDetails) MyApplication.getAndroidSession().getAttribute("cart");
        holder.cart_pro_name.setText(proItem.getP_name());
        holder.cart_pro_price.setText("Rs " + (proItem.getP_dscPer() != 0 ? details.getDiscountPrice(proItem.getP_price(), proItem.getP_dscPer()) : proItem.getP_price()));
        holder.cart_pro_qnty.setText(details.getQntyOfProduct(proItem.getPid(), proItem.getP_size()) + "");
        holder.cart_pro_size.setText(proItem.getP_size());
        String image_url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/ECommerceApp/" + proItem.getP_img();
        Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(holder.cart_pro_img);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return completeCartProItems != null ? completeCartProItems.size() : 0;
    }

    class CartItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView cart_pro_name;
        TextView cart_pro_price;
        TextView cart_pro_qnty;
        TextView cart_pro_size;
        ImageView cart_pro_img;
        ImageButton cart_remove_btn;
        Button cart_change;

        public CartItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cart_pro_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_product_name);
            cart_pro_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_product_price);
            cart_pro_size = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_size);
            cart_pro_img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_img);
            cart_pro_qnty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_qnty);
            //===============================================================================================
            cart_remove_btn = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_item_btn);
            cart_change = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_change_btn);
            cart_pro_img.setOnClickListener(this);
            cart_remove_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            cart_change.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

Fragment :

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView cart_horizontal_scroller;
    private CartItem_ScrollerAdapter cart_item_scrollerAdapter;
    private Button purchase_button;
    private List<CompleteCartProItem> completeCartProItems = new ArrayList<>();


    public CartFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void getData(MyCustomListener<CompleteCartProItem> customListener) {
        if (MyApplication.getAndroidSession().getAttribute("cart") != null) {
            Log.i("cart_null", "NOT null");
            RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue();
            CartDetails cartDetails = (CartDetails) MyApplication.getAndroidSession().getAttribute("cart");
            CopyOnWriteArrayList<CartItem> jsonSendArray = cartDetails.getShoppingList();
            final String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(jsonSendArray,
                    new TypeToken<CopyOnWriteArrayList<CartItem>>() {
                    }.getType());

            Log.i("json_object", jsonString);

            String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/ECommerceApp/getAllProductsAction";
            JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    response -> {
                        List<CompleteCartProItem> completeCart = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(),
                                new TypeToken<List<CompleteCartProItem>>() {
                                }.getType());
                        Log.i("response", completeCart.get(0).getP_name());
                        customListener.onResponse(completeCart);

                    }, error -> Log.i("Volley_error", error.getMessage())) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    params.put("cartList", jsonString);
                    return params;
                }

            };
            arrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
                @Override
                public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                    return 5000;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                    return 5000;
                }

                @Override
                public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
        } else {
            Log.i("cart_null", "null");
        }


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        cart_horizontal_scroller = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scrollView_cart_items);

        getData(new MyCustomListener<CompleteCartProItem>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(List<CompleteCartProItem> response) {
                completeCartProItems.addAll(response);
                //completeCartProItems.add(new CompleteCartProItem(1, 2340.0, "Extra Orient Top", "Orient", "", "S", 5));
                Log.i("check", completeCartProItems.get(0).getP_name());

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error_response) {

            }
        });

        cart_item_scrollerAdapter = new CartItem_ScrollerAdapter(getActivity(), completeCartProItems);

        cart_horizontal_scroller.setAdapter(cart_item_scrollerAdapter);
        cart_horizontal_scroller.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        purchase_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.purchase_btn);
        purchase_button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();
        });
        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: Strange. Can you debug with looping the response object and try adding one by one to the `completeCartProItems` list?

Comment: I dont think It will work. Because `addAll()` also does the Iterating mechanism behind the scene. But I ll try...

Comment: Yes, but you may able to set a break point inside the loop and see if it is actually adding to the list. Btw, I am not familiar with Volley but can't you set the type to `List<CompleteCartProItem>` in your `MyCustomListener's` `OnResponse` method ?

Comment: I made all the changes you asked me to do . And still getting the same result. I put Log inside the for loop and that log is also executing fine .

`public void onResponse(List<CompleteCartProItem> response) {
                    List<CompleteCartProItem> ccp = response;
                    for (CompleteCartProItem p_proItem : ccp) {
                        Log.i("check",p_proItem.getP_name());
                        completeCartProItems.add(p_proItem);
                    }
                }`

Comment: Pls try changing to `CartItem_ScrollerAdapter(Context context, List<CompleteCartProItem> completeCartProItems)` instead of `CartItem_ScrollerAdapter(Context context, List completeCartProItems)`

Comment: Change that too... :)

Comment: But I figure out one issue , At the moment debugger stops the application after executing given debug pointer still Nothing printed on the log cat according to `Log.i("check",p_proItem.getP_name());`

Comment: @BNK I m really stuck in here ... Need some help please...

Comment: If possible, please post your full project to Google Drive or One Drive or GitHub...so that we could check more

Comment: @BNK I have added my Fragment class and adapter class to my question. Please check them out. If you still cant figure out the problem , then I 'll push the project to Git and provide you the link..

Answer (score 0):

Ok. In reference to the comment above, I am writing some steps you should try since I do not have a clear picture of what might be wrong.

Let's start with your `MyCustomListener`. I do not know why are you setting the response type to `Object`. If it is to use this in multiple requests then you can modify it like the following with generics

```
public interface MyCustomListener<T> {

    public void onResponse(T response);

    public void onError(String error_response);
}
```

then use it like this when a callback is needed

```
getData(new MyCustomListener<List<CompleteCartProItem>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(List<CompleteCartProItem> response) {
        completeCartProItems.addAll(response);
      }

     @Override
       public void onError(String error_response) {
         //handle error
       }
});
```

Also make sure you are not re-initialising `completeCartProItems` elsewhere after the callback.

Not really sure if the following will fix your issue but make sure that your callback is executed in the UI thread, too.

Comment: I tried with all your requested modifications ... But still the size of `ArrayList` is 0.

Comment: If you haven't solved your problem yet, could you post your entire adapter and activity / fragment class where you are requesting the **CartProItems**

Comment: @MadushanPerera change this `public void getData(MyCustomListener<CompleteCartProItem> customListener)` to this `public void getData(MyCustomListener<List<CompleteCartProItem>> customListener)`

Comment: Are you sure I really need to make that change ??? My Interface is like below : 

`public interface MyCustomListener<T> {

    public void onResponse( List<T> response);

    public void onError(String error_response);
}`

Comment: If did so my override method would be :
`@Override
            public void onResponse(List<List<CompleteCartProItem>> response) {
                
            }`

Comment: You are trying to get List of CartProItems in OnResponse, right? Then you have to specify the type as List<CompleteCartProItems> when creating your CustomListener

Comment: But with this I can get the List of `CompleteCartProItems` . Dont you think so ???

 `public interface MyCustomListener<T> {
    /*list <CartProItems>*/
    public void onResponse( List<T> response);

    public void onError(String error_response);
}`

Comment: Could you please post your project to github and give me a link? will look into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105630/discussion-between-madushan-perera-and-much-overflow).